# Can we get short versions of URLs in question title links?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

The title on all question pages has a link to the question. These are normal links (of the form `/questions/{questionID}/{title}`), with the question's full title in the link.

They would be a lot more useful if they had the short `/q/{questionID}` links rather than what I could just copy from the address bar. This would make them a quicker character-saving way of copying the URL than copying from the share menu, which is kind of awkward sometimes (mainly on the mobile site).

It’d also be nice if the links maybe had user IDs for badges like Announcer. It *would* make them longer, but could be really quickly deleted from the links.

Comment: So, in a way, you are proposing to duplicate the functionality of the "share" button in the title of the question?

Comment: @Anton well I think it’s stupid that it’s a link but long and unwieldy. The share menu isn’t great.

Answer (score 7):

Leaving the title out of the URL entirely works fine. The title is simply for clarity for folks posting raw URLs. You can also shorten  `/question/` to just `/q/`, so the complete URL:

> `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330464/can-we-get-short-versions-of-urls-in-question-title-links`

can be quickly shortened to:

> `https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330464`

I do it all the time on the desktop and mobile; it's very quick and easy. The `share` button provides similar functionality, so it's highly unlikely we would create a second UI to pick between two character-saving ways of copying a URL — it's just too esoteric.

Answer (score 4):

The title content in the links is something I find quite valuable. People rarely add a title to their links, which makes knowing where the links go difficult. Fortunately, since we encode the title into the URL that means that I can hover over the link, read the URL and actually know which question is being linked to without clicking on it. I haven't managed to memorize the question numbers, so I'd have to actually click on links and look at the page to see what the linked question is.

Additionally, I find it frustrating when people use the short links when they're unnecessary, like in posts. In comments or chat I can understand the draw. But, you can easily shorten the links if you know the format. You can't easily make them longer.

For this reason, I oppose making a change like this.

As to adding the user id, this is something that can be problematic for some users, particularly moderators. I'd rather we include id numbers less often rather than more often.

Comment: What do you mean by “add an alt title to...links”?

Comment: Also could you please elaborate on “problematic for some users, **particularly moderators**”? What bothers mods about them?

Comment: Hmmm... I was thinking about alt text on images and assumed there was something similar for links... but if there's not, that only strengthens my reasoning as it means the URL itself is the only way to get a hint of where the link goes without using it. When mods send mod messages, they're anonymous. If they use a link with their user id, they've just outed themselves.

Comment: @storm You can add a HTML 'title' attribute to links (including images) by adding a quoted string (*"string"* or *'string'*) after the link.  See the [Markdown help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#advanced-links "And go to the 'Advanced Links' section").  For example, `[this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330464 "Can we get short versions of URLs in question title links?")` would be rendered as: [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330464 "Can we get short versions of URLs in question title links?").

Comment: Ah, thanks @ThomasF ! I thought that was possible! Yet another case where terminology bites you on the ass.